# Prevent line break in flexbox with flex-direction set to column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

HTML:

```
<div class="flex">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>two</span>
  <span>three</span>
  <span class="four">four</span>
  <span>five</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
span {
  background: #999;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.four {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

Basically the title says it - HOW do I inline the `.four` and `.five` `spans` in one line? Is it even possible? Any thoughts?

https://jsfiddle.net/erghcuhw/

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use `flex-direction: row` and then set `flex-wrap: wrap` on flex-container and `flex: 0 0 100%` on all spans except 4th and 5th.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
span {
  background: #999;
  margin-top:10px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
span:nth-child(4),
span:nth-child(5) {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.four {
   background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>two</span>
  <span>three</span>
  <span class="four">four</span>
  <span>five</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try

```css
.flexC {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexR {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexR span {
  width: 50%;
}

span {
  background: #999;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.four {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexs">
  <div class="flexC">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flexR">
    <span class="four">four</span>
    <span>five</span>
  </div>
</div>
```